# Mapping MySQL json column into JPA throws error

Tags: java, mysql, json, hibernate, jpa

I want to map MySQL JSON column into JPA. I did some research and I used

```
@Type( type = "json" )
@Column( columnDefinition = "json" )
```

But this throws an exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [json]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.ClassLoaderAccessImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderAccessImpl.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.SimpleValueBinder.fillSimpleValue(SimpleValueBinder.java:538)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SetSimpleValueTypeSecondPass.doSecondPass(SetSimpleValueTypeSecondPass.java:25)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1621)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1579)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:858)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at com.savemonk.ce.utility.hibernateAndJPA.JPAUtility.getEntityManagerFactory(JPAUtility.java:12)
    at com.savemonk.ce.v2.pricegraph.manager.AddNewPriceTrackRecord.addNewPriceTrackRecordTest(AddNewPriceTrackRecord.java:29)
    at com.savemonk.ce.v2.pricegraph.manager.AddNewPriceTrackRecord.main(AddNewPriceTrackRecord.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : json
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:336)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:345)
    ... 14 more
```

I understand that @Type is hibernate's org.hibernate.annotations.Type
What is the correct way to map the column in JPA?

I can post entity class if required.
Any links and resources which explain about JPA + JSON-type-column would help a lot.

Comment: just adding the dependency like below , worked for me:

 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
        <version>2.16.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

Answer (score 3):

There is no `json` Type in Hibernate ORM. You can use the [Hibernate Types project](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types/) which offers support for JSON.

To add support for `json`, add the following `@TypeDef` annotation to your entity:

```
@TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType.class)
```

You also need to add the following Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate-types.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Check out [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-objects-using-generic-hibernate-types/) to see how you can use the `JsonStringType` with MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Except dependency, you also need to add

`@TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType.class)`

to one of your entities class declaration

Answer (score 0):

Add dependency

> ```
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
>         <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
>         <version>2.16.2</version>
>         <scope>compile</scope>
>     </dependency>
> ```

On above your class where you are using @Type(type = "json"). Add this:

> @TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType.class)

This worked for me